# multiple classes in Criteria class

Tags: java, hibernate, class, criteria

I have two class `AcctMast`  and `DealerDtls` which are linked to their `resp.tables` `acctMast` and `dealerDtls`.

I want to use `Criteria` class in order to find out 
All dealer details whose `acctNo=XXX`,`dealerCode=XXX`,`CustCode=XXX`(Getting these three as input from my API).

But the problem is `custCode` column is present in `AcctMast` and `dealerCode` and `acctno` are the column of `DealerDtls`.
The conflict is that how to use multiple class using `Criteria` so that I can get  all the required details .

One more thing,everytime I got `custCode` and `Acctno` as input but `dealercode` is depend on user.It may be given as input or it may not means sometimes I got `dealerCode` as NULL also.

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations in class and attribute names, and tell us how these entities are mapped and what association exists between them. And clarify the last part of the question: I don't understand anything about it.

Comment: As I can understant, put Criteria Abstract, and make your three classes inherited from it

Comment: Its simple,Everytime I got custCode and AcctNo as input and I can use dealerCode as a WILDCARD i.e it may come as a input or it may not..So how do I construct my java Criteria Class so that i can get the proper output

Comment: I tried something but it didn't work for me..
Criteria criteria;
List criteriaList;
criteria=(Criteria) session.createCriteria(DealerCodeDetails.class)
.createAlias("CurrentAndSavingsAccount","casa")
   .add(Restrictions.eq("casa.id", "995"))
   .add(Restrictions.eq("codAcctNo", "000033592880"))
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("codDealer", new Integer(0)),Restrictions.isNull("codDealer")))
   .list();
System.out.println("Criteria ::::::"+criteria.list().size());
But here I got list size as 0(Zero)..

Comment: Or in other words..
I am trying to do use the Criteria class in such a way that it will run the below two queries into a single one.
Queries are as follow..

Comment: <hibernate-mapping>
   
  <sql-query name="GetCustList" cacheable="true">
  SELECT c.cod_dealer "Dealer Code",c.cod_comp_identifier "Company Identifier",c.COD_ACCT_NO "COD_ACCT_NO",c.cod_virtual_acct_no "Virtual Account Number" FROM   ch_dealer_dtls c ,ch_acct_mast d WHERE c.cod_acct_no = d.cod_acct_no  
  AND d.cod_cust= :cod_cust
     AND trim(c.cod_acct_no) =:cod_acct_no  
     AND d.cod_acct_stat not in('1','5') 
  AND c.flg_mnt_status = 'A'       
     AND d.flg_mnt_status = 'A'
     AND d.flg_mnt_status = 'A'
    </sql-query>

Comment: <sql-query name="GetCompIDList" cacheable="true">
 <return-scalar column="COD_COMP_IDENTIFIER" type="string" />
 select COD_COMP_IDENTIFIER "COD_COMP_IDENTIFIER"
   from ch_comp_identifier 
   where cod_acct_no  = :acct_no 
   and flg_mnt_status = 'A' 
 </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>